# iOS - StoreKit 2 - error handling of finish()

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

In StoreKit 2 `finish()` comes with almost no documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/transaction/3749694-finish

1. Does it connect to the internet or does it save `Transaction` status as `finished` locally and iPhone attempts to connect to the network later to inform App Store?
2. How to handle its potential errors (file I/O or no network)?

   - (I want to avoid giving consumable purchase to user twice in case `finish()` wouldn't work.)

Comment: Have you tested your scenarios? if there was a failure point the function would throw. You can't really test that apple is doing their job. If you have an issue post a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation you must provide the purchased items **before** calling `finish`. This is how you indicate to store kit that you have successfully provided the purchased item to the user.

> Call finish() to complete a transaction after you deliver the purchased content or enable the purchased service. For on-demand resources, don’t finish the transaction until the app completes downloading the resource or you’ve otherwise delivered the resource

`finish` cannot fail

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer questions 1 or 2. `finish()` can fail because providing the purchased items and calling `finish()` doesn't happen atomically, so right after providing the item and before calling `finish()` the application can crash and the item will be provided but `finish()` won't be called. Also, `finish()` must perform file I/O or network request, so that may as well fail.

Comment: You should structure your app so that it isn't really possible for it to crash between you persisting the purchase and calling `finish`.  If you app does somehow crash (which really should be highly unlikely) then the worst case is the purchaser gets a free item. If you don't follow apples guidelines and call `finish()` before you persist the purchase then the potential outcome is the user gets charged but doesn't receive their item. It is far more likely for there to be failures in your "provide the item code" than in `finish()` and the user being charged and not getting their item is bad

Comment: Also, in app purchase transactions are processed outside of your app's process. They are handled by a separate process in iOS.  Now, this is just a bit of a guess on my part, but I imagine that calling `finish` simply updates the local transaction database and the "IAP process" in iOS will ensure that the "finish" message gets to Apple eventually.  You really have to trust that Apple has put a lot of effort into making this process reliable and if they say to persist first and then call `finish` then that is what you should do.